# Custom keyword algorithm alignment

Tags: horizontal-alignment, algorithm2e

I'm trying to add a custom keyword for an algorithm block, to indicate the type of object on which the code is applied.
I tried using `\SetKW{arg1}{arg2}` but I could not insert a new line after it (the next keyword was on the same line), so I tried using the `\SetKwInOut{arg1}{arg2}`, and I succedeed, but I have a problem with colons alignment.

I'm using the following code:

```
\begin{algorithm}
    \SetAlgoLined
    \SetKwFunction{match}{exact\_match}\SetKwComment{tcp}{//}{}
    \SetKwInOut{Object}{Object}
    \Object{MyObject}
    \SetKwInOut{Input}{Input}\SetKwInOut{Output}{Output}
    \Input{my input}
    \KwResult{my result}
    \While{condition}{
        while-block\;
    }
\end{algorithm}
```

Which generates the following output:

[image]

So, even chaning the structure I used, how can I align the column of the first three fields? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`algorithm2e` provides two functions for defining these kind of pre- and postconditional keywords: `\SetKwInput{<macro name>}{<output text>}` and `\SetKwInOut{<macro name>}{<output text>}` that both define a new command `\<macro name>{<text>}`.

`\SetKwInput` typesets the `<output text>` in keyword style followed by a colon and the `<text>` the user passed as argument to the newly defined macro. `\SetKwInOut` does almost the same, but it aligns all the colons at the width of the longest `<output text>` for all the keywords that have been defined with `\SetKwInOut` previously.

As you define new macros after the first use of `\Object`, the alignment position moves, because `\Output` now gives the largest of all `<output text>` widths. That's why you get the second colon at a seemingly random position. Adding some more macro calls shows that alignment is correct, though (`\KwResult` hasn't been defined by `\SetKwInOut`  and thus doesn't get aligned):

```
\begin{algorithm}
    \SetAlgoLined
    \SetKwInOut{Object}{Object}
    \Object{My object}
    \SetKwInOut{Input}{Input}
    \SetKwInOut{Output}{Output}
    \Input{My input}
    \Output{My output}
    \Object{My object again}
    \KwResult{The final result}
    \While{condition}{
        while-block\;
    }
\end{algorithm}
```

outputs

[image]

To get proper alignment, just define all the macros you want to use in a row before using any of them:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithm2e}

\begin{document}
Non-aligned version:
\SetKwInput{Object}{Object}
\SetKwInput{Input}{Input}
\SetKwInput{Output}{Output}
\SetKwInput{Result}{Result}
\begin{algorithm}
    \SetAlgoLined
    \Object{My object}
    \Input{My input}
    \Output{My output}
    \Result{The final result}
    \While{condition}{
        while-block\;
    }
\end{algorithm}

Aligned version:
\SetKwInOut{Object}{Object}
\SetKwInOut{Input}{Input}
\SetKwInOut{Output}{Output}
\SetKwInOut{Result}{Result}
\begin{algorithm}
    \SetAlgoLined
    \Object{My object}
    \Input{My input}
    \Output{My output}
    \Result{The final result}
    \While{condition}{
        while-block\;
    }
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much!